# c# dependency injection error with interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection

I'm trying my hand at dependency injection for my RPG written in c# and some javascript.

I'm trying to inject a service into my controller but keep getting this error:

***Error activating IdownloadService No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.***

In debug mode, it fails on this line with the above error in my CharacterController class:

**public IdownloadService downloadService{ get; }**

Here is the relevant code:

*characterDownloadService.cs*

```
namespace OrionRPG.Character.Downloads
{
    public interface IdownloadService
    {
        Uri CharacterDownloadUri(int charId);
    }


    public class characterDownloadService : IdownloadService
    {

        public characterDownloadService()
        {}

        public const String CharacterServerUrl = "http://myUrl/Characters/";

        public Uri CharacterDownloadUri(int charId)
        {

            var characterName = Character.Name(charId);

            return new Uri(CharacterServerUrl + characterName); 

        }

    } 

}
```

*CharacterController.cs*

```
namespace OrionRPG.Api.Downloads
{

    public class CharacterController 
    {

         public IdownloadService downloadService{ get; }
         //inject the service
         public CharacterController(IdownloadService downloadService)
         {

             DownloadService = downloadService;

         }

         [Route("api/characters/download/{charId}")]
         public IHttpActionResult GetCharacterDownload(int charId)
         {

             return Redirect(DownloadService.CharacterDownloadUri(charId)); 

         }


    }

}
```

Comment: Did you register characterDownloadService on your DI container?

Comment: How do you register your `IdownloadService` in your DI `container`?

Comment: What DI framework are you using

Comment: you can stop debug in constructor CharacterController without problem?

Comment: @JamesDev I'm using autofac.  I did register like this:     builder.RegisterType<characterDownloadService>().As<IdownloadService>();

Comment: @StephenRoss I registered like this:     builder.RegisterType<characterDownloadService>().As<IdownloadService>();

Comment: And how do you register `CharacterController`?

Comment: `DownloadService = downloadService;` is that a typo? Did you mean `this.downloadService = downloadService;`? -- (and give the property a (private) setter)

Comment: @Corak has good point - aren't you assigning value of input variable to itself instead of assigning it to property?

Comment: CharacterController is just an .net ApiController.

Comment: @Corak I did add the 'this' in front of DownloadService, but Resharper(VS code helper add-in) said it was redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, services need to be registered to a container before injection. Different dependency injection framework might have slightly different syntax, the principles are the same.

For example, if you are using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, you will need to Register the service: In `Startup.cs` (ASP.NET Core), you will see a method named `ConfigureServices`, and you will need to register your service like this:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(); // Some code by template
...
            // This line registers the IdownloadService; when injection happens, the service provider knows to create an implementation of characterDownloadService for requested IdownloadService.
            services.AddTransient<IdownloadService, characterDownloadService>();
        }
```

For more details, check [this](https://youtu.be/cYV1JmWiTHQ) out.

Answer (score 0):

1) As I understand you are trying to use ASP.NET WebApi and it is strange that `CharacterController` doesn't inherit `ApiController`

2) You need to use Dependency Injection container which will contains all mapping between interfaces and it's implementation. I would recommend to use [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) as it is perfectly integrated with ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI. Here is a link with [docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html)